# Selecting a random ID from the 4 lowest ID in the same table

Tags: select, random, multiple-select, subquery

I would be grateful if you could help me.

I would like to write a `select statement` which would do the following:

> "Select a random ID from the 4 lowest ID in the same table"

**Note**: ID may be for example the score of students from a list of around 100 records in a table. I would like to get the 4 students with the lowest score and finally pick one record randomly.

Thanks lots

Comment: which data base are you using?

Comment: mysql database ..................... thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out about the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from tablename ORDER BY status ASC limit 4) q ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1;
```

Kindly confirmed whether it is a good answers and proper way to do the select. Any answers would be welcomes

thanks much